# Using IBM Websphere Liberty Docker Image in production

Tags: websphere-liberty

There are two images available on Docker Hub for IBM Websphere liberty.

1. https://hub.docker.com/_/websphere-liberty/
2. https://hub.docker.com/r/ibmcom/websphere-liberty/

To use the 1st image in a production environment, the licensing process is explained in https://github.com/WASdev/ci.docker/tree/master/ga/production-upgrade

But to use the 2nd image in production, no such reference is found. Requesting for some pointers here.

Comment: We can't answer that, only IBM can tell you what the exact licensing conditions are.

Answer (score 0):

As illustrated in the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/WASdev/ci.docker#docker-hub-images) you mentioned, either of these sets of images can be used in production as-is, as long as you have the proper entitlement.

If you want to apply a license to either of them, please see [this page](https://github.com/WASdev/ci.docker/tree/master/ga/production-upgrade#using-websphere-liberty-docker-in-production) which outlines the steps you can take to create a new image with the license applied.